# Estimation of sum of heavy-tailed random variables

Tags: pr.probability

I have a sum of n identically distributed random variables. But those variables have heavy-tailed distribution without expected value. How can I estimate this sum? May be there are limit theorems or laws of large numbers for this situation?

Comment: No law of large numbers, but if the law of the summands has regularly varying tails you may be in the domain of attraction of stable law, with the appropriate scaling. Open Petrov's book for more refined answers.

Comment: You didn't say anything about the dependance of the random variables. Are they independant ?